# Scrolling dynamically between Relative layouts in a scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

**I have A scroll view in which i have several relative layouts in it. And a relative Layout has two buttons add to it Dynamically.As below**

**Scroll View**

```
  _____________________
 |   ________________  |
 |  |Relative Layout|  |
 |  |   |Buttons|   |  |
 |  |_______________|               
 |                     |
 |   ________________  |
 |  |Relative Layout|  |
 |  |   |Buttons|   |  |
 |  |_______________|                 
 |                     |
 |  |Relative Layout|  |
 |  |   |Buttons|   |  |
 |  |_______________|               
 |                     |
 |   ________________  |
 |  |Relative Layout|  |
 |  |   |Buttons|   |  |
 |  |_______________|                  
 |                     |
 |  |Relative Layout|  |
 |  |   |Buttons|   |  |
 |                     |
 |_____________________|
```

Is it possible to scroll to specific relative layout dynamically on a button click.
I have already Tried below and its not working

```
if (count == 1) {
    final int k = id;
mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated
        // method stub
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
            public void run() {
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(k);
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,btn.getTop());
                }
        });
```

Scroll to also not working

Edit:
Originally I had only a set of buttons in the relative layout. Then `smoothScrollTo` was working as expected. Later I changed the structure to the above style.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, next time please add a well formatted code.

Comment: Do you have XML layout for this layout? can you post this also?

Comment: I am creating the scroll view as below in xml                                <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="88" />                                     and in the above i am adding the relative layout dynamically

Comment: add code by editing your post instead of adding a comment with it. besides that, btn.getTop(), doesnt that leave you with a relative position to its parent?, so i assume you want the position of its parent, the sourrounding Relativelayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Daniel Bo's hint was correct.

**`view.getTop()` will give position relative to its immediate parent.**

Below is the implementation.

```
ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(k); 
        ViewGroup vg =(ViewGroup)btn.getParent();
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,vg.getTop());
     }});
}
```